# TIMER OVERFLOW PIC MICROCONTROLLER?

Tags: timer, overflow, pic

I wrote a delay routine with a timer. I set the maximum value as FF.

Now that delay routine doesn't work, but the same with the maximum value of FE works?

Why shouldn't "FF" be loaded into the PIC timer register?

Comment: To get better help, provide the pic model, and the code used

Comment: Maybe due interrupt latency this value will not work. You have to give more informations

Answer (score 0):

If it is an 8 bit timer and you set it to 0xFF it increments to 0x00 very quickly and it is expired with a very short time.